# A single word for: someone who believes they were born or exist in the wrong era

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word for a person who believes that she/he was born in the wrong era/decade/time. The person desires to be either in the past or in the future. That person might also possess a certain nostalgia for a specific era.

I thought of malcontent, but I do not think this fits well. Before I start inventing a ridiculous word like malperitemporalist, I want to know if a sufficient word exists?

Comment: There's a trope: [***Born in the wrong century***](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BornInTheWrongCentury). You might also like the slightly-repurposed [***temporal dissonance***](http://christopherrei.blogspot.com/2013/10/temporal-dissonance-and-me.html).

Comment: Anachronist sounds right though I don't think it's considered a word. Do you mind making up your own?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had not thought of anachronism as a noun, but I think anachronist will do. No, I do not mind making up my own words, but what use are they if no one else can easily understand them?

Comment: Ugh, how I loathe having to resort to tropes... But I do like the second term you mention; temporal dissonance certainly could work.

Comment: The person believes s?he is *behind his/her time* or *ahead of his/her time*

Comment: @Drew: And what of someone like me, who lives in the  cultural past, but works in the technical future?

Comment: @jamesqf: Technically, you do future work in your past.

Comment: "Eraoneous", obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Anachronistic.

> Noun,
>    something or someone that is not in its correct historical or chronological time, especially a thing or person that belongs to an
>   earlier time

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/anachronism)

Comment: Please include your source next time.

Comment: Ananchronistic is not a noun!

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the felt they were **born out of time**

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out_of_time

> At the wrong time or period.
>   ‘I felt that I was born out of time’